# Button OnClick only return works on first element

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to web design. I have multiple generated lines of MySQL database elements that I want to make changes to, but when I click on button to show, it only show the first button even if I click the second or third "Add".

[image]

```
<body>
    {% for trail in trails %}
        <div>
            <form>
                {% csrf_token %}
                TrailName:{{trail.1}}
                AreaName:{{trail.2}}
                City:{{trail.3}}
                Length:{{trail.8}}
                RouteType:{{trail.11}}
                AvgRating{{trail.12}}
            </form>
            <button onClick="show()">Add</button>
        </div>
        <div class="part">
            <form action="insert_schedule" method="POST">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <input type="radio" name="trailid" value="{{trail.0}}">
                schedule date:
                <input type="date" name="schedule_date">
                <input type="submit" value="Ok">
            </form>
            <button onClick="hide()">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</body>
```

```js
function show() {
    var show_part = document.querySelector(".part");
    show_part.style.display = "block";
}

function hide() {
    var show_part = document.querySelector(".part");
    show_part.style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: `.querySelector()` only returns the first match - the first `<div>`.  So as written, `hide()` and `show()` will only ever have an effect on the first one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the HTML structure you show:

```js
function show(el){
  const show_part = el.parentElement.nextElementSibling;
  show_part.hidden = false;
}

function hide(el){
  const show_part = el.parentElement;
  show_part.hidden = true;
}
```

and change your `button` code to

```html
<button type="button" onclick="show(this)">Cancel</button>
.
.
.
<button type="button" onclick="hide(this)">Cancel</button>
```

Comment: When I directly copy these codes, the button onlick="show(this)" did not show the div and form? Am I missing something?

Comment: You probably have some CSS like `.part { display: none; }`. Remove that, and instead Render your `div.part` with a `hidden` attribute by default (if hidden is the default initial state): `<div class="part" hidden> ... </div>`.